# check if an input string is of a specific pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, java.util.scanner

How do I check if the user inputs a String in a particular pattern. I want the user to input a number, then a comma, followed by a number again. For example, `3,3` or `4,4`. If the user enters for eg: `3,,3` it should not be accepted.

Comment: please choose an answer as accepted

Answer (score 3):

Use regex `\d+` match numbers groups:

```
 String input = "3,3";
 System.out.println(input.matches("\\d+,\\d+"));  // should be true
```

update:

If more than two numbers are allowed, use `(\\d+,)+\\d+` to match multiple groups.

Comment: String has a built in matches Method, so the easiest way is: input.matches("\\d+,\\d+"). See vogellas Tutorial for more details: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: @BenjaminMesing It should be the best solution!

Comment: @Vishakha check the comment of user Benjamin Mesing, it should be the best!

Comment: That's wrong, this regex will only validate if the pattern is `\d,\d`. Input can also be `\d,\d,\d`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I did not take that into consideration, updated.

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) and try it some stuff there.

For your question, use the next pattern: `\d+,\d+`

Answer (score 0):

Since the question labeled with `Scanner` I assume that you want to use it, so you can do it this way

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
if (sc.hasNext("\\d+,\\d+")) {
    // code for good case
} else {
    // not matched
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public class Demo3 extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText edt;
private Button b;
private TextView tv;
private String days;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo3);

    edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!edt.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                String[] split_space = edt.getText().toString().split(",");// TODO: Check if input is actually an Integer , Integer.
                if (split_space.length == 2) {
                    if(isValidInteger(split_space[0]) && isValidInteger(split_space[1])){
                        tv.setText("accepted");
                    }else{
                        tv.setText("not accepted (contains characters)");
                    }
                } else {
                    tv.setText("not accepted (doesn't respect format (3,3 or 4,4 or ...))");
                }
            }else {
                tv.setText("not accepted (empty)");
            }

        }
    });
}

private boolean isValidInteger(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            Integer val = Integer.valueOf(value);
            if (val != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

demo3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edt"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="null"
    android:id="@+id/tv"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/b"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String str= null;

if(scan.hasNext("\\d+,\\d+")){
 str = scan.next();
}

if(str != null){
 System.out.println("Valid User Input: {"+str+"} Recieved");
}
else{
 System.out.println("Invalid User Input");
}
```

**str** would be equal to null if the pattern doesnot match